# Dar nombre a las claves (keys) de un array

Tags: php, array

Buenas queria preguntarles si existe la posibilidad de darle un nombre a mis datos del array que traigo con este codigo.

```
$filas=file('Avis.log');  
$results = collect([]);
$array = [];
foreach($filas as $llave => $v ){
        foreach (explode("<", $v) as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == $v) {
                $result = null;
            } elseif (strpos($value, ">") !== FALSE) {
                $results->push(substr($value, 0, strpos($value, ">")));
                $array[$llave][$key]=substr($value, 0, strpos($value, ">"));
            } else {
                $result = null;
            }
        }
    }
    dd($array);
    return view(GetDiseno('admin.uipath.index'))
    ->with("results",$array);
```

me da este resultado

[image: darle nombre al 1 , 2 , 3, 4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8]

Hay alguna forma de darle un nombre al 1 , 2 , 3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partiendo del siguiente array simple como ejemplo.

```php
$array = array(1 => "Agendada",  
               2 => "07/11/2019 17:19:41", 
               3 => "00:00:31.9665009",
               4 => "11/07/2019 23:00",
               5 => "David Graterol",
               6 => "Medicina General",
               7 => "13285523-4",
               8 => "Correcto"
              );
```

Puedes probar a cambiar el nombre de cada llave con **unset()** de una forma similar a la siguiente:

```php
$array["nombre del primero"] = $array[1];
unset($array[1]);

$array["nombre del segundo"] = $array[2];
unset($array[2]);

$array["nombre del tercero"] = $array[3];
unset($array[3]);

$array["nombre del cuarto"] = $array[4];
unset($array[4]);

$array["nombre del quinto"] = $array[5];
unset($array[5]);

$array["nombre del sexto"] = $array[6];
unset($array[6]);

$array["nombre del septimo"] = $array[7];
unset($array[7]);

$array["nombre del octavo"] = $array[8];
unset($array[8]);
```

El resultado sería un array como el siguiente:

```sh
Array
(
    [nombre del primero] => Agendada
    [nombre del segundo] => 07/11/2019 17:19:41
    [nombre del tercero] => 00:00:31.9665009
    [nombre del cuarto] => 11/07/2019 23:00
    [nombre del quinto] => David Graterol
    [nombre del sexto] => Medicina General
    [nombre del septimo] => 13285523-4
    [nombre del octavo] => Correcto
)
```

Si lo que deseas es realizarlo en un ejemplo más parecido al propuesto, como por ejemplo el siguiente array (que a su vez contiene otros dos subarrays):

```php
$array = array(
               1=> array(1 => "Agendada",  
                         2 => "07/11/2019 17:19:41", 
                         3 => "00:00:31.9665009",
                         4 => "11/07/2019 23:00",
                         5 => "David Graterol",
                         6 => "Medicina General",
                         7 => "13285523-4",
                         8 => "Correcto"
                    ),
               4=> array(1 => "Agendada",  
                         2 => "07/11/2019 17:19:41", 
                         3 => "00:00:31.9665009",
                         4 => "11/07/2019 23:00",
                         5 => "David Graterol",
                         6 => "Medicina General",
                         7 => "13285523-4",
                         8 => "Correcto"
                    )
                );
```

Puedes utilizar un **foreach** para tratar cada sub array de la misma manera que en el ejemplo simple anterior.

```php
foreach($array as &$elemento){
   $elemento["nombre del primero"] = $elemento[1];
   unset($elemento[1]);
   $elemento["nombre del segundo"] = $elemento[2];
   unset($elemento[2]);
   $elemento["nombre del tercero"] = $elemento[3];
   unset($elemento[3]);
   $elemento["nombre del cuarto"] = $elemento[4];
   unset($elemento[4]);
   $elemento["nombre del quinto"] = $elemento[5];
   unset($elemento[5]);
   $elemento["nombre del sexto"] = $elemento[6];
   unset($elemento[6]);
   $elemento["nombre del septimo"] = $elemento[7];
   unset($elemento[7]);
   $elemento["nombre del octavo"] = $elemento[8];
   unset($elemento[8]);
}
print_r($array);
```

De esta manera tendrás un resultado parecido a lo siguiente:

```php
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre del primero] => Agendada
            [nombre del segundo] => 07/11/2019 17:19:41
            [nombre del tercero] => 00:00:31.9665009
            [nombre del cuarto] => 11/07/2019 23:00
            [nombre del quinto] => David Graterol
            [nombre del sexto] => Medicina General
            [nombre del septimo] => 13285523-4
            [nombre del octavo] => Correcto
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [nombre del primero] => Agendada
            [nombre del segundo] => 07/11/2019 17:19:41
            [nombre del tercero] => 00:00:31.9665009
            [nombre del cuarto] => 11/07/2019 23:00
            [nombre del quinto] => David Graterol
            [nombre del sexto] => Medicina General
            [nombre del septimo] => 13285523-4
            [nombre del octavo] => Correcto
        )

)
```

Comment: Al utilizar la primera forma me sale el siguiente error Undefined offset: 1

Comment: Entiendo que si el array solo tiene dos subarrays, y cada uno de esos dos subarrays tiene solo 8 elementos, no debería de dar dicho error. El error puede deberse a que hay más de 8 elementos en el array.

Comment: Son mas de subarrays son muchos( error mio no ponerlos todos) el tema es que siempre tiene 8 elementos pero son muchos subsarrays

Comment: De ser asi no debería haber problema si utilizas la segunda forma del ejemplo, la que es más parecida a lo propuesto, ya que al utilizar el foreach, da igual el numero de subarrays que haya, con tal de que cada uno de ellos tenga 8 elementos siempre no debería de dar errores.

Answer (score 0):

Si tus datos vienen en el mismo orden siempre, puedes cambiar los nombres y crear un nuevo array asociativo.

```
$nuevo_datos = [];

$datos = [
   [
        1 => 'data 1',
        2 => 'data 2',
        3 => 'data 3',
   ],
   [
        1 => 'data 1',
        2 => 'data 2',
        3 => 'data 3',
   ]
];

foreach ($datos as $arr) {
    $dato = [];
    $dato['agenda'] = $arr[1];
    $dato['otro'] = $arr[2];
    $dato['otro'] = $arr[3];
    array_push($nuevo_datos, $dato);
}
```

esto te daría en tu array `$nuevo_datos` un estructura como la siguiente:

```
$nuevo_datos = [
    [
      'agenda' => 'valor',
      'otro' => 'valor',
      'otro' => 'valor
    ],
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción que nos evitará tener que escribir código redundante, puede ser utilizando `array_combine`, ejemplo:

### Opción 1

```
<?php
// nuestro array
$values = array(
               1 => array(1 => "Agendada",  
                         2 => "07/11/2019 17:19:41", 
                         3 => "00:00:31.9665009",
                         4 => "11/07/2019 23:00",
                         5 => "David Graterol",
                         6 => "Medicina General",
                         7 => "13285523-4",
                         8 => "Correcto"
                    ),
               2 => array(1 => "Agendada",  
                         2 => "07/11/2019 17:19:41", 
                         3 => "00:00:31.9665009",
                         4 => "11/07/2019 23:00",
                         5 => "David Graterol",
                         6 => "Medicina General",
                         7 => "13285523-4",
                         8 => "Correcto"
                    )
                );
// las claves que queremos asignar a los elementos
$keys = array('agenda', 'create', 'hora', 'update', 'nombre', 'categoria', 'code', 'estado');

// al ser multidimensional recorremos con un foreach
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    // utilizamos array_combine para para establecer las claves del arrya
    // asignamos al array inicial 
    $values[$key] = array_combine($keys, $value);
}

print_r($values);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [agenda] => Agendada
            [create] => 07/11/2019 17:19:41
            [hora] => 00:00:31.9665009
            [update] => 11/07/2019 23:00
            [nombre] => David Graterol
            [categoria] => Medicina General
            [code] => 13285523-4
            [estado] => Correcto
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [agenda] => Agendada
            [create] => 07/11/2019 17:19:41
            [hora] => 00:00:31.9665009
            [update] => 11/07/2019 23:00
            [nombre] => David Graterol
            [categoria] => Medicina General
            [code] => 13285523-4
            [estado] => Correcto
        )

)
```

---

También podemos tirar de `array_map()` junto con `array_combine()` para obtener el mismo resultado en una sola línea, ejemplo:

### Opción 2

```
<?php
// nuestro array
$values = array(
               1 => array(1 => "Agendada",  
                         2 => "07/11/2019 17:19:41", 
                         3 => "00:00:31.9665009",
                         4 => "11/07/2019 23:00",
                         5 => "David Graterol",
                         6 => "Medicina General",
                         7 => "13285523-4",
                         8 => "Correcto"
                    ),
               2 => array(1 => "Agendada",  
                         2 => "07/11/2019 17:19:41", 
                         3 => "00:00:31.9665009",
                         4 => "11/07/2019 23:00",
                         5 => "David Graterol",
                         6 => "Medicina General",
                         7 => "13285523-4",
                         8 => "Correcto"
                    )
                );
// las claves que queremos asignar a los elementos
$keys = array('agenda', 'create', 'hora', 'update', 'nombre', 'categoria', 'code', 'estado');
// aplicamos un array_map utiizando una funcion anonima y haciendo uso de `use ($keys)`
// para pasarle las claves nuevas, en la función anónima aplicamos el array_combine
$values = array_map(function($v) use ($keys) { return array_combine($keys, $v); }, $values);

print_r($values);

?>
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [agenda] => Agendada
            [create] => 07/11/2019 17:19:41
            [hora] => 00:00:31.9665009
            [update] => 11/07/2019 23:00
            [nombre] => David Graterol
            [categoria] => Medicina General
            [code] => 13285523-4
            [estado] => Correcto
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [agenda] => Agendada
            [create] => 07/11/2019 17:19:41
            [hora] => 00:00:31.9665009
            [update] => 11/07/2019 23:00
            [nombre] => David Graterol
            [categoria] => Medicina General
            [code] => 13285523-4
            [estado] => Correcto
        )

)
```

El requisito para utilizar array_combine es que los 2 arrays que reciben tengan la misma longitud. Puedes obtener mas informacion en la documentacion de PHP [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php) y [`array_combine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-combine.php)